# Why does adding a generic type to a trait affect the lifetime of trait objects and associated types?

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime, associated-types, trait-objects

I have following code:

```rust
trait T<GT> {
    type AT;

    fn foo(&self);
}

struct AbstractT<GT, AT> {
    t: Box<dyn T<GT, AT = AT>>,
}

impl<GT, AT> T<GT> for AbstractT<GT, AT> {
    type AT = AT;

    fn foo(&self) {
        self.t.foo();
    }
}

fn boxed_abstract<GT, TT: T<GT> + 'static>(tt: TT) -> Box<dyn T<GT, AT = TT::AT>> {
    Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f09cb723bd0744b1b9003a0b45aac53d)

Which throws these errors:

```rust
error[E0310]: the associated type `<TT as T<GT>>::AT` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound `<TT as T<GT>>::AT: 'static`...
note: ...so that the type `AbstractT<GT, <TT as T<GT>>::AT>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0310]: the parameter type `GT` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:20:5
   |
19 | fn boxed_abstract<GT, TT: T<GT> + 'static>(tt: TT) -> Box<dyn T<GT, AT = TT::AT>> {
   |                   -- help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `GT: 'static`
20 |     Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
note: ...so that the type `AbstractT<GT, <TT as T<GT>>::AT>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/lib.rs:20:5
   |
20 |     Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If I remove `GT` from everywhere, it compiles just fine, but with `GT` it fails with a bunch of lifetime errors. It seems that existence of `GT` should not affect lifetimes of either `dyn T` or `T::AT` (because it's not used in them), but it apparently does. Likewise, lifetime of `dyn T` should not depend lifetimes of `GT` or `AT` but it apparently does.

Am I missing something or is it a lifetime inference problem?

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing something. Rust automatically infers lifetime bounds for trait objects, in the case of boxed trait objects the automatically inferred lifetime bounds is `'static`. For example, this what the Rust compiler sees when it looks at your code:

```rust
trait T<GT> {
    type AT;

    fn foo(&self);
}

struct AbstractT<GT, AT> {
    // notice the added "+ 'static" below
    t: Box<dyn T<GT, AT = AT> + 'static>,
}

impl<GT, AT> T<GT> for AbstractT<GT, AT> {
    type AT = AT;

    fn foo(&self) {
        self.t.foo();
    }
}

// notice the added "+ 'static" in the return type
fn boxed_abstract<GT, TT: T<GT> + 'static>(tt: TT) -> Box<dyn T<GT, AT = TT::AT> + 'static> {
    Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
}
```

To make it compile we just need to add more explicit `'static` bounds on all your generic types like so:

```rust
trait T<GT> {
    type AT;

    fn foo(&self);
}

struct AbstractT<GT, AT> {
    t: Box<dyn T<GT, AT = AT>>,
}

impl<GT, AT> T<GT> for AbstractT<GT, AT> {
    type AT = AT;

    fn foo(&self) {
        self.t.foo();
    }
}

fn boxed_abstract<GT, TT>(tt: TT) -> Box<dyn T<GT, AT = TT::AT>>
    where TT: T<GT> + 'static, GT: 'static
{
    Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=01ecb52a40127c0135c178d1f6d189b9)

The reason why we need all these `'static` bounds is simple: a container type can only be bound by `'static` if all of the types inside of it are bound by `'static` and so on recursively.

Further reading:

- [Default Trait Object Lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html#default-trait-object-lifetimes)

**Update**

If you don't like the `'static` requirement you can make `AbstractT` generic over lifetimes by adding an explicit lifetime annotation to its type, like so:

```rust
trait T<GT> {
    type AT;

    fn foo(&self);
}

struct AbstractT<'a, GT, AT> {
    t: Box<dyn T<GT, AT = AT> + 'a>,
}

impl<'a, GT, AT> T<GT> for AbstractT<'a, GT, AT> {
    type AT = AT;

    fn foo(&self) {
        self.t.foo();
    }
}

fn boxed_abstract<'a, GT, TT>(tt: TT) -> Box<dyn T<GT, AT = TT::AT> + 'a>
    where TT: T<GT> + 'a, GT: 'a
{
    Box::new(AbstractT { t: Box::new(tt) })
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=84d77a31c579c1b1cdeb819459d2d516)

Comment: Well, T is not a container. It does not contain either GT or AT. Its lifetime should not put requirements on GT or AT lifetime, right?

I don't want GT or AT to be static.

And without GT rust is perfectly capable of understanding that T lifetime does not depend on AT lifetime.

Comment: So my question is:
1. Why adding GT makes rust think that T lifetime is constrained by AT lifetime?
2. How to work around it, i.e. have `T: 'static` while AT/GT are not.

Comment: @FLashM You're right, AT's lifetime doesn't need to be constrained by T's lifetime, I've updated my answer to reflect that. Also, I updated my answer to include a version of the solution without any dependencies on 'static.

Comment: If you preserve the original `TT: 'static` constraint you don't need to add a parameter to `AbstractT` in order to make `boxed_abstract` work: [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=836c933c7993cd31791ffc802cb16fcb). However, you wouldn't be able to stuff the returned `Box` into another layer of `AbstractT` because `AbstractT` itself requires `'static`.

Comment: Hm. Interesting, so restricting GT relieves requirement on AT. However, question on GT still stands. GT lifetime does not affect T lifetime, is there a way to make boxed_abstract work without restricting GT lifetime?